# Curve is regular

Tags: calculus

There is a question that asked me to consider that the curve is regular, but at first how do I check? read * a * as $\alpha.$

$$ a(r) = (e^{r} \cdot \sin(r), e^r, e^{r} \cdot \cos(r) )$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$a'(r)=e^r( \sin r+ \cos r, 1, \cos r- \sin r).$$

Now you see that $a'$ is continuous, hence $a$ is a $C^1$- function.

It is easy to see that $a'(r) \ne (0,0,0)$ for all $r$.

That's all.

Comment: To be regular you have to have $ a '(r) \neq 0$ for any value of r, right?

Comment: Yes, $a'(r) \ne 0$ for all $r$.

Comment: If I can only verify that a function is continuous in a Ponyo (checking if the limit on the point is equal to the function on ponde as long as the point is in the domain), in this case how do I do it?