# Consider that the curve is regular

Tags: calculus, functions

There is a question that asked me to consider that the curve is regular, but at first how do I check? read * a * as $\alpha.$

$$ a(r) = (e^{r} \cdot \sin(r), e^r, e^{r} \cdot \cos(r) )$$

I got given the [following solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469491/curve-is-regular):

> We have
>
> $$a'(r)=e^r( \sin r+ \cos r, 1, \cos r- \sin r).$$
>
> Now you see that $a'$ is continuous, hence $a$ is a $C^1$- function.
>
> It is easy to see that $a'(r) \ne (0,0,0)$ for all $r$.
>
> That's all.

I can recognize that a function is continuous, if it is a polynomial for example. But what about in this case?

Comment: You've asked the same question two hours ago ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curve is regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3469491/curve-is-regular)

Comment: @MichaelHoppe If I can only verify that a function is continuous in a Ponyo (checking if the limit on the point is equal to the function on ponde as long as the point is in the domain), in this case how do I do it?